# autoit - IE click a button based on its text.

Tags: autoit

I have a button on a form that I need to click and it looks something like this

```
<button id="****" class="****">Click Me</button>
```

I am using the following code to click other buttons which works fine but that is because the other buttons has a `value="*****"` assigned to it

```
$oButtons = _IETagnameGetCollection($oIE, "button")
For $oButton in $oButtons
    If String($oButton.value) = "Click Me" Then
       _IEAction($oButton, "click")
    EndIf
Next
```

I know that the `$oButton.value` is what is getting the value for the button, but what other "operator" is there besides `value` that can get the anchor text of the button?

Comment: `innerText` or `innerHtml` would be educated guesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example that you posted should be used only in a situation when you don't have an ID of the element. ID is always unique.

If the button that you want to click has an ID, you can use it as a reference to that button.

**EXAMPLE:**

HTML:

```
<button id="MyButton" class="someClass">Click Me</button>
```

CODE:

```
$oBtn = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "MyButton")
_IEAction($oBtn, "click")
```

Apart from .Value you can use all of the below:

```
$oBtn.innerText
$oBtn.outerText
$oBtn.innerHtml
$oBtn.outerHtml
$oBtn.classname
$oBtn.id
$oBtn.name
$oBtn.href
$oBtn.src

$oBtn.click
$oBtn.focus
...
```

Note that you can use $oBtn.value to read or write to the "Value" property of the html element, but for eg. "itemProp" property $oBtn.itemProp won't work

**EXAMPLE:**

HTML:

```
<button id="MyButton" class="someClass" itemprop="streetAddressSubmit" >Click Me</button>
```

This wont work:

```
$ItempropValue = $oBtn.itemprop
```

This is how it should be done:

```
$ItempropValue = $oBtn.getAttributeNode ('itemprop').NodeValue
```